# random instance of distribution and Variance Calculation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1, X_2,...X_20$ be a random instance of distribution with following probability function:

$F(x)= (0.3)^x(0.7)^{1-x}, X=0,1.$

My TA‌ Solve Variance of $S_20= \Sigma_{i=1}^{20}X_i$ to `0.21`. i think this is wrong, and do lots of try with this concept, but I couldn't get it. any description or idea? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TA indeed seems to be wrong: with $p=0.3$ and $n=20$, we have
$$
\text{Var}(X_i)=p(1-p)=0.21,\quad\text{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{20}X_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{20}\text{Var}(X_i)=4.2.
$$
Each $X_i$ follows a Bernoulli distribution whereas $S_{20}$ follows a binomial distribution $B(n,p)$.